# Swift Scroll down should make Bar Item disappear

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uinavigationitem

I want that the Bar Button Item diappear when I scroll down. My problem is that I don't know how to detect the scroll? I have tried some code but nothing worked. For example:

`func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("123")
}`
(Don't work, I call the method in viewDidLoad())

Also I don't know where I have to call the method. In viewDidLoad(), viewDidAppear() or somewhere else? I am new in Swift, sorry.

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you are calling it from viewDidLoad, that gets called only once when the view is loaded. You need to place this `scrollViewDidScroll` 
 function separately, after viewDidLoad for example, but not inside of it.

Also make sure you implemented `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your file. Then you can add `scrollViewDidScroll` method to detect when is the view scrolled and `print('123')` inside of it.

Also make sure to set your `scrollView.delegate = self` in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks. I added UIScrollViewDelegate and place scrollViewDidScroll after viewDidLoad. But when and where do I have to call the function? When I write "override" in front of  scrollViewDidScroll I get the error: "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: You should not override it and it should be called automatically when you scroll, you do not need to specifically make a call to that function once it is declared it will get called automatically

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, but I doesn't work: Did I do something wrong? Here the code:                           (Line 1)@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! (Line 2)       
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("123")
    }

Comment: Did you add `scrollView.delegate = self` in your viewDidLoad ?

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help :)  I edit my answer to mention that `scrollView.delegate = self`